# Room SQL autogenerate primary key returning 0 or null

Tags: android, mysql, android-room

So My database was working with one Website entity

```
 @Entity(tableName = "website_table") public class Website {

     @NonNull
     @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
     private Integer websiteId;

     private String title;
     private String base_URL;
     private String description;


     public Website(String title, String base_URL) {
         this.title = title;
         this.base_URL = base_URL;
     }

     public void setWebsiteId(Integer websiteId) {
         this.websiteId = websiteId;
     }

     public Integer getWebsiteId() {
         return websiteId;
     }

     public String getTitle() {
         return title;
     }

     public String getDescription() {
         return description;
     }

     public void setDescription(String description) {
         this.description = description;
     }

     public String getBase_URL() { return base_URL; }

     public void setBase_URL(String base_URL) { this.base_URL = base_URL; }
   }

@Dao
public interface WebsiteDao {

    @Insert
    void insert(Website website);

    @Update
    void update(Website website);

    @Delete
    void delete(Website website);

    @Query("DELETE FROM website_table")
    void deleteAllWebsites();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM website_table ORDER BY title DESC")
    LiveData<List<Website>> getAllWebsites();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM website_table")
    public List<WebsiteWithWebPages> loadWebsitesWithWebPages();
}
```

Then I tried to add a relationship for webpages on a website

```
    public class WebsiteWithWebPages {
        @Embedded
        public Website website;

        @Relation(parentColumn = "websiteId", entityColumn = "website_Id", 

        entity = WebPage.class)
        public List<WebPage> webPageList;
    }

@Entity(tableName = "webpage_table")
public class WebPage {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public Integer webPageId;

    public final String name;
    public final String url;
    public String description;
    public final Integer website_Id;

    public WebPage(String name, String url, final Integer website_Id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.url = url;
        this.website_Id = website_Id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public Integer getWebsiteId() {
        return website_Id;
    }
}
```

When I try to add websites using my website Dao, for example using command

```
Website website= new Website("website name", "websiteurl");
        websiteDao.insert(website);
```

My app crashes. each website created is given an id of 0 and FOREIGN KEY constraint failed. What is going wrong here? I changed the primarykey from int to INTEGER, and when I did that it set the primary key as null, and when primarykey is int, it sets id to 0. Whats going on?

Comment: change you primary key data type from Integer to int and check , it should work

Comment: @pinakin That's the thing, it doesn't. I already changed to integer after it stopped working. My code was working for int primary keys with one entity. When I added the second entity, I now face a foreign key constraint failed as all the auto-generated IDs are 0.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. In the end I redid my code. This time, I copied from https://github.com/Pavneet-Sing/RoomDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/pavneet_singh/roomdemo/AddNoteActivity.java

Specificially, for the DoInBackground for the 'Insert' Async Task, there is the code `

```
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... objs) {
            // retrieve auto incremented note id
            long j = activityReference.get().noteDatabase.getNoteDao().insertNote(note);
            note.setNote_id(j);
            Log.e("ID ", "doInBackground: "+j );
            return true;
        }
```

And by having the Insert Dao method return long

```
 @Insert
    long insertNote(Note note);
```

The database properly auto assigns ids as expected. Also take note in the order that notes are being added if many are added at once. In this situation, the ids wont be set as the call to insert to the database is creating an async method each time. So what I did was add a .get() after each async call to make sure everything was set properly on time